# Depending on size of the calculator's display - why no article in front of "size"?

Tags: grammar, articles

An excerpt from *Pi: A Biography of the World's Most Mysterious Number*:

> The theme of this book is understanding π and some of its most beautiful aspects. So we should begin out discussion and exploration of π by defining it. While for some people π is nothing more than a touch of the button on a calculator, where then a particular number appears on the readout, for others this number holds an unimaginable fascination. Depending **on size** of the calculator's display, the number shown will be...

Why is it not **depending on the size of the calculator**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - it should be "**the** size of the calculator's display."